# How to change the administrator account name from command prompt in Windows Server 2008 Server Core?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I'm trying to change the administrator account name on my virtual machine for lab work purposes.  I'm running Windows Server 2008 Server Core, therefore I'm only using the standard command prompts.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

If it domain user install Active Directory Administration module for PowerShell.

command line:

```
powershell Import-module ActiveDirectory
```

rename domain user -

Powershell:

```
Get-ADUser -Identity 'Administrator' | Rename-ADObject -NewName 'Partisan'
```

command line:

```
powershell Get-ADUser -Identity 'Administrator' ^| Rename-ADObject -NewName 'Partisan'
```

var 2:

```
dsquery user -name Administrator | dsmove -newname "Partisan"
```

local administrator -

Powershell:

```
Rename-LocalUser -UserName 'Administrator' -NewUserName 'Partisan'
```

command line:

```
powershell Rename-LocalUser -UserName 'Administrator' -NewUserName 'Partisan'
```

var2:

```
wmic UserAccount where Name="Administrator" call Rename Name="Partisan"
```